# Can the administration of self-report measures of craving prompt participants with addiction to experience craving during the experiment?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, neuroscience, methodology, neuroimaging, addiction

My research focuses on measuring *the neural correlates* (through resting-state EEG) pre-post an improvisational music therapy session (MT sessions) *in clients with substance misuse.*
One of my variable of interest is the urge to consume the drug = namely, ***craving*** [(Volkow et al., 2015)](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/25734247/) .

I was thinking to use some subjective measure of craving pre and post the MT sessions to associate this with the pre/post resting-state EEG measures.
I've been found in the scientific literature similar procedures in the work of [De Ridder research group:](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/21458537/) the authors associated the subjective measures collected pre-post an experimental manipulation with the neural data (EEG)  collected pre-post an experimental manipulation.

Participants will have to complete the following statement: ***"please, rate how strong your craving is right now by circling a number on the 10-point scale"***...In which 0=not craving at all and 10=the most ever

Since craving is a complex construct that has been related to addiction memories and can be triggered by environmental cues ([Chen et al., 2018](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6306924/); [Huang et al., 2018](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-017-18471-y)) I am afraid to prompting them and induce a craving response during the MT session that wouldn't have happened.

> **Is that possible that using a self-report assessment of craving,**
> **participants are required to reflect on their experiences entailing a**
> **craving response that otherwise would have been absent?**

Comment: This to me **is** a risk with self-report measures. It would be interesting to see what studies confirm such a risk and at what level.